# having trouble using JavaScript or Ajax and text display the same page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm having mistakes do not know where error

Having trouble using JavaScript or Ajax and text display the same page

Please help me in the wrong reform

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>pop up example</title>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener("submit",upload);
function upload()
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST","/upload.php",true);        
    {
        var formdata = new formData(myform);
        xhr.send(formdata);
    }
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
    {
             //some code to check if submission succeeded 
             url = xhr.responseText();
             if(url == 'failed')
                  Console.log('upload failed'); // do something for failure
             else
                  document.getElementById('urlBox').innerHTML = url;
    }
}; return false;
}
    </script>
</head>


<body>



<form id="myform" method="POST" action=<?php ($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>>

    <p>chose url: 
    <select size="1" name="D1">
        <option value="google_drive">google drive</option>
        <option value="clody">clody</option>
    </select>    
    <input type="text" name="T1" size="40">    
    <input type="submit" value="go" name="B1">
    <input type="reset" value="reset" name="B2">
    </p>
</form>


 </body>

</html>
```

and this upload.php file

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['D1']) && !empty($_POST['T1'])){
    $providers = array(
        'google_drive' => 'Goole drive^https://drive.google.com/file/d/{replace}/view',
        'clody' => 'Cloudy^https://www.cloudy.ec/embed.php?id={replace}'        
    );

    if(isset($providers[$_POST['D1']])){

        $url =  str_replace('{replace}', $_POST['T1'], $providers[$_POST['D1']]);
        echo "$url";
    }
}

else{
   echo "failed";
}
?>
```

and thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Add following line in your html page

```
<div id='urlBox'></div>
```

Comment: There are some other error also, check error console in your browser and let me know the result

Comment: I am tired of attempts I did not find a solution so far
I hope that you find the solution you have :(

Answer (score 0):

It is normal your semicolon after `xhr.open("POST","/upload.php",true)` ?

Comment: I'm sorry I did not understand your question
Forgive my English a little weak

Comment: @awn500 you missed ';' at the end of the line. xhr.open("POST","/upload.php",true);

Comment: hmm It does not exist
I've just been confirmed to be present

Comment: Do you speak French ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try replace this line:

```
<form id="myform" method="POST" action=<?php ($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>>
```

For this:

```
<form id="myform" method="POST" action="<?php ($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
```

The differece is in your action. You're not using ""