# str replace problemem code

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['D1']) && !empty($_POST['T1'])){
    $providers = array(
        'google_drive' => 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/{replace}/view',
        'clody' => 'https://www.cloudy.ec/embed.php?id={replace}',
        'example' => 'http://example.com/log.php?id={replace}&name={replace2}&pass={replace3}'
    );

    if(isset($providers[$_POST['D1']])){

        $url =  str_replace('{replace}', $_POST['T1'], $providers[$_POST['D1']]);
        echo "Your url is $url";
    }


}
?>

<form method="POST" action=<?php ($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>>
    <p>chose url: 
    <select size="1" name="D1">
        <option value="google_drive">google drive</option>
        <option value="clody">clody</option>
        <option value="example">example</option>
    </select>    
    <input type="text" name="T1" size="40" value="insert code">    
    <input type="submit" value="go" name="B1"><input type="reset" value="reset" name="B2">
    </p>
</form>
```

i want run `{replace}&name={replace2}&pass={replace3}`

Comment: you posted practically the same question back in Nov. 2016 http://stackoverflow.com/q/40802230/1415724 you mean to tell me that you didn't get that going since?

Comment: @Fred-ii-  'example' => 'http://example.com/log.php?id={replace}&name={replace2}&pass={replace3}'

Comment: @Fred-ii- works fine but I want to add {replace2} and {replace3} Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this one and implement proper naming convention.

```
$provider = 'clody'; // replace with $_POST['D1']
$replacementText = 't1-text'; // replace with $_POST['T1']
$providers = array(
        'google_drive' => 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/{replace}/view',
        'clody' => 'https://www.cloudy.ec/embed.php?id={replace}',
        'example' => 'http://example.com/log.php?id={replace}&name={replace2}&pass={replace3}'
    );
$url = str_replace('{replace}', $replacementText, $providers[$provider]);
echo "Your url is " . $url;
```